# UV unwrapping isn't working

Tags: uv

so I'm getting into unwrapping and I am confused at the results I'm getting. I have my UV editor viewport and my 3D viewport. I create a new UV texture map, "head" so I can single out my head from the body and unwrap it. I create the seam around the neck and unwrap it. And the UV editor does... nothing. It just creates this tiny vertex in the bottom left corner, but the confusing part is that when I click on it, it highlights a *random edge on my characters back.* You can see the seam I marked in this image and the edge it highlights.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Smart UV Projection does work though.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Just to narrow down the issue, does *Smart UV Project* work?

Comment: Hello, smart UV projections does work.

Comment: Okay. Backup your object and apply all transforms *Object > Apply > All Transforms*. Then try your unwrapping again. If it still won't work, you can [upload your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) :).

Comment: Tried that, didn't work... sharing the file now. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fz7ffk2uR5CTqGtm407ChKUq8Ej29QXo/view?usp=sharing or [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=vYSx4N5V" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/vYSx4N5V/)

Comment: Weird. It works just fine for me :). Are you sure you selected all faces before unwrapping?

Comment: Could you link an image of the result you get or list your steps? Are you doing anything different from me? Unwrapping the seam at the neck unwraps the head and body on different islands in the UV editor?

Comment: Sure, in a minute :).

Comment: No I didn't select all the faces before unwrapping because I'm an idiot and didn't realize I had to do that first. It does what I need it to now, thank you.

Comment: No problem :). You were smart enough to ask others for help. Good luck, the model looks real good.